# I want to create a wizard when I am clicking save button

Tags: python-2.7, odoo-8

I am working in odoo-8 I want to create a wizard when I am clicking save button, am not having any idea can anybody give me some suggestion.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to confirm the changes before a save? I'll need some more information about what you're trying to do before I can be a better help.

Note - I know this is not an answer right now, but I can't ask for more information in a comment until I have 50 reputation points! Sorry